# Keeping canvas in the same position during scrolling

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, zooming

I have some problems with zooming wpf canvas control. I zoom canvas using ScaleTransform operation which is provieded by WPF. The problem is that canvas location is changing during zooming. Is there any efficient (and simple) way to keep the scroll position intact during zooming operation ?? I konow I could set a scroll position myself every time but it will be unefficient

Answer (score 1):

How about using LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform? You didn't mention which one you were using, but because LayoutTransform is not changing the position i guess you used the later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something that maintains scroll position while zooming, have a look at > http://www.codeproject.com/KB/docview/WpfZoomAndDragPanel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CenterX and CenterY of the ScaleTransform.  That is what controls what's in the middle of the display and it's how you can keep your zoom centered.